# Rails method to get all descendant categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Previously, I was shown a concise and excellent way to get all ancestor categories for a given category in a rails application:

```
def ancestors
  result = []
  c = self
  while c.parent
    result.unshift(c.parent)
    c = c.parent
  end
  result
end
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get all of the descendant categories for a given category (children, children of children, etc.)  The nearest I've been able to get is the following, but I  still have the problem where the final result array is messed up. The top level arrays aren't closed.  I've been wrestling with this for hours and am not sure how to fix it.

```
def descendants

  result = []
  c = self

  for child in c.children
   result.push(child)
   if(child.children.any?)
    result.push(child.descendants)
   end
  end

  result

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def descendants
  children.map(&:descendants).flatten
end

def ancestors
  [parent, parent.try(:ancestors)].compact.flatten
end
```

Manual tree traversing has performance implications. You should consider using a gem like [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) which does a very good job of tree representation.

**Edit 1**

If you are using the `awesome_nested_set` gem, please note that it has `ancestors` and `descendants` methods on AR instance. You can sort the results of these methods using ruby (If you are dealing with a small set  < 100).

```
category.descendants.sort_by(&:name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and check out the ancestry gem.  I was using awesome_nested_set but I need an easy way to sort the categories by name or other attribute.  This is critical for me and it seemed like this was difficult to do with nested sets.

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Thank you!  The sorting method for awesome_nested_set worked for me.  That's what I needed.  Also, I found that when I returned result.flatten from my descendants method in the original question, it worked.  Learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: I see that I can sort awesome_nested_set children (e.g. current_category.children.sort_by(&:name), but when I do the whole list Category.all.sort_by(&:name), it will mess up the nesting.  Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: What do you mean by `it will mess up the nesting`?

Comment: I think my problem was with form helper to list the categories in a select box.  I was using it incorrectly.  It should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Also acts_as_tree is a great gem by Rails: https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree

I use it for this very purpose and it automates it all.